# Yii: Change Sql request used for pagination

Tags: php, pagination, yii

I'am trying to use the pagination with Yii and everything is working fine! But (there is always a but ^^) the request executed to get the number of object is not optimized:
In my Controller I have the following code:

```
<?php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
                        'with' => array('series', 'author', 'stars'),
                        'condition' => "etat = " . 1,
                ));
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(News::model(), array(
                        'pagination' => array(
                                'pageSize' => 10,
                        ),
                        'criteria' => $criteria,
                ));
?>
```

And the request performed for the pagination by CPagination is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
FROM `news` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news_serie` `series_series` ON (`t`.`id`=`series_series`.`id_news`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `serie` `series` ON (`series`.`id`=`series_series`.`id_serie`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` `user` ON (`t`.`id_user`=`user`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news_stars` `stars_stars` ON (`t`.`id`=`bonhommes_bonhommes`.`id_news`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `stars` `stars` ON (`stars`.`id`=`stars`.`id_stars`) 
WHERE (etat = 1)
```

This request is way to complicated in this case and I would Like to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `news` `t`  WHERE (etat = 1)
```

So my question is: How could i change the request to get the total number of news?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple! All I had to do is set the totalitemCount value in my Provider with the request i wanted:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(News::model(), array(
                        'pagination' => array(
                                'pageSize' => 10,
                        ),
                        'criteria' => $criteria,
                        'totalItemCount' => News::model()->count('etat = 1'),
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can probably try this...

```
$itemCount = $dataProvider->getTotalItemCount();
```